# How do I align an img within the div after appending it with javascript?

Tags: javascript

After appending an image to a div with javascript, I wanted to align the image within it's container, but every time I use `top` in the div `img {}` all images snap to the top of the container, overlapping. I have created a codepen  : [here](https://codepen.io/lisaschumann/pen/RmmJEj).

As the main website is build in wordpress, I am unable to make the main div a flex box as the icon is written before the text in their HTML file. The way they had it set up is that the text is aligned to the center and the icon is floating to the right.

```
 <div>
    <span><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
    <a href="#">Text</a>
  </div>
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="1">
      <a href="#">Nummer 1</a>
      <span><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div id="2">
      <a href="#">Nummer 2</a>
      <span><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  background-color: red;
  border: 5px solid white;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

div a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

div img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
}

span {
  color: white;
  float: right;
}
```

**JS:**

```
window.onload=function(){
  var elem = document.createElement("img");
  elem.src = "https://lisaschumann.github.io/resources/images/Icon_Test.png";
  elem.height = 40;
  elem.width = 40;
  elem.alt = "icon";
  document.getElementById("1").appendChild(elem);

    var elemTwo = document.createElement("img");
  elemTwo.src = "https://lisaschumann.github.io/resources/images/Icon_Test.png";
  elemTwo.height = 40;
  elemTwo.width = 40;
  elemTwo.style = "background-color: blue";
  elemTwo.alt = "icon";
  document.getElementById("2").appendChild(elemTwo);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute position works regarding the relative positioned parent element. So you have to make the containing div relative positioned:

`position: relative;`

You can also do this dynamically with javascript:

```
  elem.parentElement.style.position = 'relative';
  elemTwo.parentElement.style.position = 'relative';
```

```js
window.onload=function(){
  var elem = document.createElement("img");
  elem.src = "https://lisaschumann.github.io/resources/images/Icon_Test.png";
  elem.height = 40;
  elem.width = 40;
  elem.alt = "icon";
  document.getElementById("1").appendChild(elem);

    var elemTwo = document.createElement("img");
  elemTwo.src = "https://lisaschumann.github.io/resources/images/Icon_Test.png";
  elemTwo.height = 40;
  elemTwo.width = 40;
  elemTwo.style = "background-color: blue";
  elemTwo.alt = "icon";
  document.getElementById("2").appendChild(elemTwo);
  }
```

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  border: 5px solid white;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

div a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

div img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 30px;
}

span {
  color: white;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="1">
      <a href="#">Nummer 1</a>
      <span><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div id="2">
      <a href="#">Nummer 2</a>
      <span><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks so much for your quick help! That worked! Can I ask you - is there any way to make the JS code more compact and combine them or is this the correct way?

Comment: The easiest i can think of is if you simply make a function which adds image to a given element. Like so: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MddPXM

Comment: Thanks so much Peter! That was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Would it help if you changed your `div img` to the following:

```
div img {
  float: left;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

It seems to center the divs the way I understood that you wanted.

Comment: Thanks so much Yosefc! I ended up using the absolute + margins!